# Capture image of window or widget in Mono

Tags: c#, linux, image, mono, cross-platform

I'm trying to capture an image of either the current window or a widget and save it to an image file. The problem is that I'm using Gtk# on Mono, so it needs to be a solution that'll work with that.

Essentially, something like this:

```
myWidget.SaveImage("imageFile.png");
```

I'd prefer a PNG or JPEG, but a raw bitmap will do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using Gdk.

This is very similar to this question: [How to take a screenshot with Mono C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719685/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-mono-c)

I've also found a php-gtk example here: http://php-gtk.eu/code-hints/grabbing-a-screenshot-with-gdk

Comment: Not what I want to do. If another window is displayed on top, my window will be obscured. I want to capture an image regardless of its state or position - even if the window is minimised.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure that isn't going to be possible without getting help from the window manager.

Comment: "regardless of state" sounds a little odd, widgets respond to different events, including resize, mouse, focus etc. In what context do you need this? ( You might be able to do somthing with a compositing window manager )

Comment: I'm producing graphs on a monitoring frontend, and they need to periodically be dumped to images.

Comment: Oh, right, a screenshot of a gtk widget doesnt sound like what you want then. How are you drawing your graphs? If you use Cairo you will find it easier I think to do both the drawing and capture.

Comment: The graphs are generated by the library.