# Capturing screen in C# on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, mono, screenshot

Is it possible to do interface calls to CGWindow API from C# on OSX in Mono ?

If not, what is the easiest way of doing fast screen captures in C# on OSX? I'm using Mono as an IDE.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Have you tried [this](http://www.mono-project.com/Screenshots) approach yet?

Comment: Thank you. Which approach are you referring to ?

Comment: [This one](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/) and [this one](http://www.nunit.org/).  Sorry about that!

Comment: @Brian all the links you've posted seem totally irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @ipmcc How is posting two links to frameworks that support what the OP was asking about 'irrelevant'?

Comment: @Brian: OP is asking about taking screenshots on OSX from Mono, and you posted links to "Screenshots **of** the mono apps", then you posed two more links, one to NClass, "A Free UML Class Designer" and another to NUnit, a .NET unit testing framework. Call me dense, but I don't think any of these are relevant to the challenge of calling OS X system API from Mono in hopes of taking screenshots.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719685/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-mono-c : the question seems very similar.