# How to take screenshot every few seconds C# console

Tags: c#, macos, mono, console-application, screenshot

I am making a c# console application that takes a screenshot every 20-40 seconds.

I've tried looking everywhere, but all other examples don't use the console

This is the code I have made so far:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FizzBuzz
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void ScreenShot()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int sleepTime = rnd.Next(20, 40);
            int num = 0;
            while (num == 0)
            {
                Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
                {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                    }
                    bitmap.Save("screenshots.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(sleepTime*100);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScreenShot();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code I get a long error message on the console like this:

[image: error message]

Comment: You are using mono?

Comment: I think I  am using mono

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719685/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-mono-c

Comment: @jeroenh thanks for sending the link, my code is working now!

Comment: Can you add reference System.Windows.Forms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using ScreenTest;
using System.Threading;


namespace ScreenTest
{
    public class PrintScreen
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of the entire desktop
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Image CaptureScreen()
    {
        return CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
        // get te hDC of the target window
        IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
        // get the size
        User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
        User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
        int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
        int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
        // create a device context we can copy to
        IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
        // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
        // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
        IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
        // select the bitmap object
        IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
        // bitblt over
        GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
        // restore selection
        GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
        // clean up
        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

        // get a .NET image object for it
        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
        // free up the Bitmap object
        GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

        return img;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Captures a screen shot of a specific window, and saves it to a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle"></param>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <param name="format"></param>
    public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        Image img = CaptureWindow(handle);
        img.Save(filename, format);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Captures a screen shot of the entire desktop, and saves it to a file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename"></param>
    /// <param name="format"></param>
    public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        Image img = CaptureScreen();
        img.Save(filename, format);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
    /// </summary>
    private class GDI32
    {

        public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
            int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
            int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
            int nHeight);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
    /// </summary>
    private class User32
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

        }
    }
}

namespace Screentest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\\ss");
            if (!di.Exists) { di.Create(); }


            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(20, 40) * 1000);
                PrintScreen ps = new PrintScreen();
                ps.CaptureScreenToFile(di + $"\\screenShoot{Guid.NewGuid()}.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
}
```